# Two different startActivity methods lead to same activity when they shouldnt?

Tags: android

So in my app I've got a menu screen, and two different buttons. They should link to two different activities, however whichever one I press it links to the same activity. Code is below.

```
public class MenuScreen extends Activity {
    Button btnGoToClassic, btnGoToTowerDef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_screen);

       btnGoToClassic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGoToClassic);
       btnGoToTowerDef = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGoToTowerDefense);

        btnGoToClassic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeScreen.class));
            }
        });
        btnGoToTowerDef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TowerDefense.class));
            }
        });
       };
```

however both of these go to "HomeScreen" (confusing name, just the name of one of my activities, not the default menu screen)

any ideas why it's doing that? I've been trying to fix it for a while now but with no success

Comment: Are you sure your layout (xml) looks correct? E.g no duplicate id's on your buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that something inside of `TowerDefense` is starting `HomeScreen`? Try putting in log statements in `onCreate` for each of your classes and observe the call sequence.

Comment: ooh thanks so much, just checked through my code and you're absolutely right, I guess that's what happens when you get lazy and copy + paste too much code! Readjusting code now, will report back to tell you if it works